# PrimeNg TurboTable - Conditional Row-grouping

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable, primeng-turbotable

I am using PrimeNG's TurboTable (p-table)

I have a `groupField` parameter, which can either be `null` or have a value corresponding to a column header. This param's value can be changed dynamically at any time. The expected behaviour is that when `groupField==null` a normal table is rendered but when 'groupField==` then the rows group as per this value, as seen [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/rowgroup).

I want to implement rowgrouping as described [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/rowgroup) where the table responds to the changes in the `groupField` parameter.

**What I have tried:**

1. Make two ng-templates with `pTemplate="body"`, something like this.

> ```
> <ng-template pTemplate="body" *ngIf="groupField==null">
>     ...
> <ng-template>
> <ng-template pTemplate="body" *ngIf="groupField!=null">
>     ...
> <ng-template>
> <ng-template pTemplate="rowexpansion" *ngIf="groupField!=null">
>     ...
> <ng-template>
> ```

This **does not work** as I suspect that p-table forms its config when it first renders and subsequently only updates data.

2. Make two different `<p-table>`s, one with rowgrouping and the other without, with `ngIf` to control which one shows at a given time. This **works** but does not make sense to me as I should be able to do this in one table, as I was able to in the older `<p-datatable>`.

What I would like is to have ONE table handle all of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an `<ng-container>` inside your `<p-template>` so it would look something like this:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body">
   <ng-container *ngIf="groupField==null">
    ...
   </ng-container>
   <ng-container *ngIf="groupField!=null">
    ...
   </ng-container>
<ng-template>
<ng-template pTemplate="rowexpansion" *ngIf="groupField!=null">
    ...
<ng-template>
```

You can check it working here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-stack-55706959?file=src/app/ils-tree/ils-tree.component.ts

There is a `groupField` that you can change from true to false in the `tablegrouping.component.ts` to check how it works.